# Sum of absolute differences, What does maxSAD stand for?

Tags: correlation, template-matching

I'm working on a project regarding image processing, and i'm currently working on my subsystem that had to do with template matching and i'm implementing the SAD technique ( Sum of Absolute Differences ) in order to find a match between several images. I have implemented the code and is working fine. My question is about a minSAD value i am using. It is predefined to a value of a 100000. And the way i understand it is that as lower the minSAD is the more accurate the match we find will be. I just need to find out more about it as I've searched and nothing seems to describe it in a detailed way. Just need this explanation to understand it better for myself so any help would be appreciated.

```
minSAD = VALUE_MAX;

// loop through the search image
for ( int x = 0; x <= S_rows - T_rows; x++ ) {
    for ( int y = 0; y <= S_cols - T_cols; y++ ) {
        SAD = 0.0;

    // loop through the template image

    for ( int j = 0; j < T_cols; j++ )
            for ( int i = 0; i < T_rows; i++ ) {

                pixel p_SearchIMG = S[x+i][y+j];
                pixel p_TemplateIMG = T[i][j];

                SAD += abs( p_SearchIMG.Grey - p_TemplateIMG.Grey );
            }

        // save the best found position 
        if ( minSAD > SAD ) { 
            minSAD = SAD;
            // give me min SAD
            position.bestRow = x;
            position.bestCol = y;
            position.bestSAD = SAD;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can anyone even begin to guess what you're asking if you don't include the relevant code?

Comment: @PaulR i included the pseudocode i used to implement it. i just need to know a bit more about the minSAD = VALUE_MAX

Comment: OK - so you may need to fix the question, as it appears you're talking about `minSAD`, not `maxSAD` ? Anyway, the pseudo code is pretty self-explanatory - it just searches for the location with the minimum SAD value. `minSAD` is initialised to a large value, and then whenever a lower value is found it us updated with the new min value and the location is recorded.